# Lenght of a capture group in regex

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a program which matches a password requirement. The criteria is something like this:

```
##>digits|letters(need to be as much as the digits)|symbols(also need to be as much as the digits)<##
```

Here is an example:

```
##>00|no|NO|!!!?<### - no match
##>123|yes|YES|!!!<## - match
$$<111|noo|NOPE|<<>$$ - no match
```

Can someone help me please.

Comment: I don't think this is possible in a regexp, it doesn't have counters.

Comment: This should be done in a programming language, it can compare lengths.

Comment: `regex` is not the most appropriate tool for this goal. It can be used to check that a string contains the classes of characters that are required in a password but it is much easier (and the code is more clear) to iterate over the input string, classify and count the characters it contains.

Answer (score 1):

It's not that difficult if you know the count of the digits.

If that count is *5* for example then I believe this will do `[0-9]{5}\|[a-zA-Z]{5}\|[^a-zA-Z0-9]{5}`.